# throw exception in the try block rather than catch block?

Tags: c#, exception

I've inherited code in our project which looks like this.  It's a method in a class.

```
protected override bool Load()
{
    DataAccess.SomeEntity record;

    try
    {
        record = _repository.Get(t => t.ID.Equals(ID));

        if (record == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("failed to initialize the object.");
        }
        else
        {
            this.ID = record.ID;
            // this.OtherProperty = record.SomeProperty;
            // etc
        } 
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If I then call this Load method from my UI layer, I'd probably want to have a try catch block to catch any exception caused by the failure to Load the instance, e.g. InvalidOperationException, but the above code feels wrong to me.

Won't the InvalidOperationException be swallowed by the catch statement? that catch statement will also catch potential problems with _repository.Get, as well as potential problems with the setting of properties if the record is valid.

I thought I should perhaps restructure it by adding more try catch statements to handle the Get operation and property setting operations separately, or add more catch blocks handling different exceptions, but I asked a colleague, and he suggested that the try catch is irrelevant in this case, and should be removed completely, leaving it like:

```
protected override bool Load()
{
    DataAccess.SomeEntity record;

    record = _repository.Get(t => t.ID.Equals(ID));

    if (record == null)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("failed to initialize the object.");
    }
    else
    {
        this.ID = record.ID;
        // this.OtherProperty = record.SomeProperty;
        // etc
    } 

    return true;
}
```

I'd like some second opinions, I've only just started taking an interest in exception handling, so I'd like to make sure I am doing it the right way according to best practices.

Comment: Your colleague was correct. Both versions do the same, so why not have less code?

Comment: I would suggest that *throw* has been left in there from debugging - with that piece of code you can place a breakpoint on the *throw*, and then inspect the exception (using `$exception` in the immediate window). Doing this is useful when you are not sure yet exactly what could pop out of there, and as the other posters have said it has no effect otherwise.

Answer (score 6):

When you do this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

You are essentially not handling the exception. That does not however mean you are ignoring it. The `throw` statement will propagate the exception up the stack. For the sake of clean readable code your final example is much better.

Comment: Really the only reason to have this code (without anything before the `throw`) is to attach a debugger (rather than Debug | Exception which is global).

Comment: Only catch exceptions that you know need to be caught. I typically leave out any try catch blocks unless I know exactly why I need it in a particular situation. Leave the error handling off until you absolutely need it - start off with a single global error handler at the highest point in the application - if this is asp.net you can hook the application error event and log errors there, but my point is don't add try catch blocks unless you know why your adding them and write code that handles error cases not traps them.  Also its is not necessary to rethrow an error if you remove the try catch

Answer (score 0):

If you're catching exceptions in the calling method ( Ithink) you should **only catch exceptions which you expect**. If the exception is a problem for Load(), then throw a new exception to the calling method, with better information about the exception.

Comment: Make that "exceptions which you *can handle*". There and plenty of exceptions you can expect, but, at this point in the code, can do nothing useful.

Answer (score 0):

Excellent! You are definitely on the right track. The previous implementation doing nothing other than re-throwing exceptions which is unnecessary. You should only handle specific exceptions that you are anticipating in the business layer, otherwise let them naturally go up the call stack up to the UI layer.

As best practice, only re-throw exceptions when you want to add some additional debug information, in which case you will need to define a custom exception

Answer (score 0):

The exception *will* be caught by the `catch` statement but since it has a `throw` statement, it'll throw the exception back out. This has the same effect as if you didn't have a try/catch  at all, so your colleague is right in suggesting leaving it out.

There isn't much of a point to adding exception-handling code if you don't actually handle the exception in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your colleague, you should only catch exceptions that you know need to be caught.  I typically leave out any try catch blocks unless I know exactly why I need it in a particular situation.  This is because you tend to hide the real bugs in your code if you just put try catch block around everything.  Leave the error handling off until you absolutely need it - start off with a single global error handler at the highest point in the application - if this is asp.net you can hook the application error event and log errors there, but my point is don't add try catch blocks unless you know why your adding them and write code that handles error cases not traps them.

Enjoy!